# How to not write more bytes than are in the buffer in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple copy program. It reads `test_data.txt` in chunks of 100 bytes and copies those bytes to `test_dest.txt`. I find that the destination file is at least one unit of `chunk` larger than the source file. How could I adjust it so that just the right number of bytes are copied? Would I need a copy buffer of size 1?
Please not the point is to solve it using low level I/O system calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() { 

    int fh  = open("test_data.txt", O_RDONLY);
    int trg = open("test_dest.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

    int  BUF_SIZE = 100;
    char inp[BUF_SIZE]; 

    int read_bytes = read(fh, inp, BUF_SIZE);
    while (read_bytes > 0) {
        write(trg, inp, BUF_SIZE);
        read_bytes = read(fh, inp, BUF_SIZE);
    }   

    close(trg);
    close(fh);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `read` function just told you how many bytes it read. You should `write` that amount of bytes:

```
write(trg, inp, read_bytes);
```

---

On another note, you really should check for failures from the `write` call as well. And definitely the `open` calls.

On yet another note, you only really need *one* call to `read`:

```
ssize_t read_bytes;  // The read function is specified by POSIX to return a ssize_t
while ((read_bytes = read(fh, inp, sizeof inp)) > 0)
{
    write(trg, inp, read_bytes);
}
```

Comment: trying to get the basic I/O right just for the moment now but thanks for emphasising it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not standard C11. Check by reading the standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and read before the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book.

Your code is more or less [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), and certainly compiles on most Linux distributions, e.g. [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) (you want to install their `build-essentials` metapackage).

**Please read the documentation** of [open(2](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)), [read(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), every [syscalls(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) you are using, and of [errno(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Notice that **each of the functions you are calling can fail, and your code should test for the failure case**. Also be aware that a `write` (or a `read`) could be partial in some cases, and this is documented.

### Recommendation:

with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -the usual C compiler on most Linux distributions, compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

### Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Learn to [use the GDB debugger](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Read about [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (a very common tool on most Linux systems) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org).

Be aware of [strace(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). You might use it on [cp(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html), or study the source code of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) (providing `cp`).

Remember that **most Linux distributions are mostly made of [open source](https://opensource.org/) software**.

### You are allowed to study their source code.

I even believe that **you *should* study their source code**, at least for inspiration !

> I'm trying to write a simple copy program. It reads test_data.txt in chunks of 100 bytes and copies those bytes to test_dest.txt

If performance matters, the chunk size of 100 bytes is really too small in practice. I would recommend a power of two bigger than 4Kbytes (the usual [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) size on x86-64).